# Unable to start rabbitMq on suse 11

Tags: rabbitmq

I am unable to start rabbitmq on my computer. I am unable to understand why it won't start. I have added the log here.

```
node           : rabbit@localhostapp descriptor : /export/home/common/rabbitmq/2.1.0/rabbitmq-server/scripts/../ebin/rabbit.app
home dir       : /export/home/common
cookie hash    : YnX6g+D++llq4lsfy4TwsA==
log            : /export/home/common/rabbitmq/current/rabbitmq-server/log/rabbit@localhost.log
sasl log       : /export/home/common/rabbitmq/current/rabbitmq-server/log/rabbit@localhost-sasl.log
database dir   : /export/home/common/rabbitmq/current/rabbitmq-server/mnesia/rabbit@localhost
erlang version : 5.8.1

starting file handle cache server                                     ...done
starting worker pool                                                  ...done
starting database                                                     ...BOOT ERROR: FAILED
Reason: {function_clause,[{lists,usort,
                                 [{[rabbit@localhost],
                                   [rabbit@localhost]}]},
                          {rabbit_mnesia,init_db,2},
                          {rabbit_mnesia,init,0},
                          {rabbit,'-run_boot_step/1-lc$^1/1-1-',1},
                          {rabbit,run_boot_step,1},
                          {rabbit,'-start/2-lc$^0/1-0-',1},
                          {rabbit,start,2},
                          {application_master,start_it_old,4}]}
Erlang has closed
{"Kernel pid terminated",application_controller,"{application_start_failure,rabbit,{bad_return,{{rabbit,start,[normal,[]]},{'EXIT',{rabbit,failure_during_boot}}}}}"}

Crash dump was written to: erl_crash.dump
Kernel pid terminated (application_controller) ({application_start_failure,rabbit,{bad_return,{{rabbit,start,[normal,[]]},{'EXIT',{rabbit,failure_during_boot}}}}})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few possibilities, but by far the most likely cause is that the directory you've configured (or has been set by default) for the mnesia database files is not writable by the user you're running rabbitmq as.

Comment: thank you for your hint. I had to remove the old mnesia directory and created the new one and it started working.